# Declaration of template specialization on a template function

Tags: c++, arduino-c++

I'm getting `undefined reference to ´long long fromBigEndin<long long>(unsigned char*)´` for a template specialization.

See code here: https://onlinegdb.com/AagKTQJ2B

I have this structure:

`util.h`

```cpp
template <class T>
T fromBigEndin(uint8_t *buf);

template <>
int64_t fromBigEndin<int64_t>(uint8_t *buf);
template <>
long long fromBigEndin<long long>(unsigned char *buf);
```

`util.cpp`

```cpp
template<class T>
T fromBigEndin(uint8_t *buf) {
    T number = 0;
    uint8_t nBytes = sizeof(T);
    uint8_t i;

    for (i = 0; i < nBytes; i += 1) {
        number += buf[i] << (16 * (nBytes - i - 1));
    }

    return number;
}
```

`headerImpl.h`

```cpp
#include "util.h"

void handleOpenSession(uint8_t *data) {
    uint8_t *uid = (uint8_t *)malloc(8);
    memcpy(uid, data + 1, 8);
    int64_t uidNbr = fromBigEndin<int64_t>(uid);
}
```

From @AnoopRana response, putting the implementation in header file works, I would like to know if it is possible to put the implementation in a separate file.

Any idea on how could I force the compilation of `fromBigEndin<int64_t>()`?

I've also tried to move the specializations to `util.cpp` but doesn't work either.

The code itself works when in a single file and with different declarations:

- https://www.mycompiler.io/view/9YRi89BnZa0
- https://www.mycompiler.io/view/HvvI1H6RUWi

Comment: Seems for classes it it possible: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file, what I'm asking is if it is possible to do it with functions

Comment: Method 2 works now. I have updated the example. Earlier i made small typo in method 2 so that's why it were' working. See [demo method 2](https://onlinegdb.com/wiuwROG4f)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Method 1

You need to put the implementation of the function template into the header file itself. So it would look something like:

**util.h**

```
#pragma once  //include guard added
template <class T>
T fromBigEndin(uint8_t *buf);

//definition
template <> int64_t fromBigEndin<int64_t>(uint8_t *buf)
{
    return 53;
}
//definition 
template <> long long fromBigEndin<long long>(unsigned char *buf)
{ 
    return 54;
}


//implementation in header file itself
template<class T>
T fromBigEndin(uint8_t *buf) {
    T number = 0;
    uint8_t nBytes = sizeof(T);
    uint8_t i;

    for (i = 0; i < nBytes; i += 1) {
        number += buf[i] << (16 * (nBytes - i - 1));
    }

    return number;
}
```

**headerImpl.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "util.h"

void handleOpenSession(uint8_t *data) {
    //add code here 
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "util.h"
int main()
{
    
    return 0;
}
```

[Working demo](https://onlinegdb.com/aDEDXCRdn)

##### Method 2

Here we make use of explicit template instantiations.

**util.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <cstdint>
template <class T>
T fromBigEndin(uint8_t *buf);
```

**headerImpl.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "util.h"


void handleOpenSession(uint8_t *data) {
    uint8_t *uid = (uint8_t *)malloc(8);
    memcpy(uid, data + 1, 8);
    int64_t uidNbr = fromBigEndin<int64_t>(uid);
}
```

**util.cpp**

```
#include "util.h"

template<class T>
T fromBigEndin(uint8_t *buf) {
    T number = 0;
    uint8_t nBytes = sizeof(T);
    uint8_t i;

    for (i = 0; i < nBytes; i += 1) {
        number += buf[i] << (16 * (nBytes - i - 1));
    }

    return number;
}

//no angle brackets used here
template int64_t fromBigEndin<int64_t>(uint8_t *buf);
template long long fromBigEndin<long long>(unsigned char *buf);
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>

#include "util.h"
int main()
{
    
    return 0;
}
```

[Working demo](https://onlinegdb.com/oGn0zCbCTa)

Comment: Yes, this works, but I'm trying to put the implementation on a cpp separate file. From what I've seen it seems possible to put it separated, if it is not, I will accept this solution

Comment: This is the question, when I try method 2, it fails with `undefined reference`

Comment: If you try it, it does not work

Comment: I have the demo, but cannot save (don't have an account) I will save in brief

Comment: Check method 2 error here: https://onlinegdb.com/AagKTQJ2B

Comment: @Miquel I made a small typo while writing method 2. [Here](https://onlinegdb.com/hYABMh6eS) is the updated link. Note there should be no angle brackets as commented in my demo example.